# How to dynamically set currency symbol in Excel custom format?

Tags: excel, formatting, format

The figures in my spreadsheet use the following custom formatting:

```
€#,###.##,, "M"
```

So figures are expressed in millions with 2 decimal places prefixed by the euro symbol and followed by M for millions.
My workbook will need to be converted to other currencies and I don't want to have to change the custom format everywhere.

Is it possible to dynamically set the currency symbol for custom formats so that I don't have to hard-code the € symbol and I could just set the currency once per workbook?

Comment: You can define conditional formatting (setting the number format) based on a given cell's value or some other trigger.  How do you want to dynamically set this?  Change a master cell's value from `$` to `€`?

Comment: Yes, by changing a master cell value ideally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a named style. They're on the Home tab, hiding under the colourful section where "Normal", "Bad", "Neutral" and so on can be seen.

Click the drop-down belonging to this section of the ribbon. I'll assume that in this case we'll change the format named Currency down at the bottom, but you can change any one of these, or even create your own:

1) Right-click on the Currency style and select Modify...
2) On the dialog box that appears, use the Format... button
3) This in turn opens the usual Format Cells dialog box.
4) Using the Custom category, create your custom formatting as you normally would.
5) Use OK once and then again to close the various styling boxes and return to your sheet.

Once done, any time in future you want to format an area, click open the Styles drop-down to retrieve your customized Currency style.

When you need to change currency symbol en masse for a sheet, you then just need to perform steps 1-5 again to replace the old symbol with the new symbol in the custom code. All cells in the spreadsheet that are marked as Currency will flip over to the new symbol.